# Ubuntu Server, listen for commit on external SVN repository?

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I have a Subversion repository which my team and I use for source control on a web application we are building. I would like to be able to have every commit to that repository automatically publish to our testing server. I have checked out the repository to a working copy on the server... is there any way to listen to the repository on the server so that every time somebody commits to the repository I can run a svn update?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [post commit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html). [Here](http://imrannazar.com/Automated-Deployment-with-Subversion)'s an example.

Comment: Is there any way to implement that on the client side instead of the server side? I don't have direct access to the server where the repository is hosted, so doing a server-side hook will be difficult.